# Regular expression for a hostname

Tags: regex, syntax, hostname

I'm trying to match a hostname similar to `foo-bar3-vm.companyname.local`.  The part that is `foo-bar3` can be any combination of letters, numbers, and hyphens, but I want to ensure it ends in `-vm.companyname.local`.

I was attempting to use `/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[vmVM]*\.companynanme\.local$/`, but that seems to match anything ending in `.companyname.local`.

What's wrong with my regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[vmVM]*` portion means *match the letters v,m,V, or M zero or more times*, so zero repetitions would give you a string ending in just `.companyname.local`. If you want to be as restrictive as your question makes it sound, just change it to something like:

`/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-]*\-[vV][mM]\.companyname\.local$/`

Or, if you want *at least one* letter/number in the hostname, something like:

`/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*\-[vV][mM]\.companyname\.local$/`

Edit: Whoops, typo.

Answer (score 1):

The `*` means "zero or more times", and `[...]` means any character from this group. So `[vmVM]*` means "any of v, m, V or M repeated zero or more times".

What you actually want is:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-]*-vm\.companynanme\.local$/i
```

Note the "i" on the end means "case insensitive"

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[-]{1}[vV]{1}[mM]{1}\.companynanme\.local$/
```

The `{1}` quantifier will ensure that you have a hyphen `-`, one `v` followed by one `m`.

The `*` quantifier means you can have zero or more occurrences of the `[]` expression. Hence, anything that ends with `.companyname.local` will match the regular expression posted in your question.

Comment: The quantifier `{1}` for any regex atom is redundant.

Comment: I know this is a little late, but I feel the previous commenter didn't state this strongly enough:  **`{1}` has absolutely no effect.**  `[-]{1}[vV]{1}[mM]{1}` is exactly the same as `[-][vV][mM]`.